# Trouble to connect to SQLite3 Database (Google Chrome)

Tags: vbscript, sqlite

I'm trying connect to SQLite3 Database of Google Chrome using VBScript with a goal of capture all visited urls stored in "History" database of Google Chrome browser.

My trouble is that when will go connect comes a error that say:

> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] "Data source name is very long."

Here is my last attempt done:

**PS:** *EDITED with suggestion of @Ekkehard.Horner.*

```
Const LOCAL_APPLICATION_DATA = &H1c&

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(LOCAL_APPLICATION_DATA)
Set objFolderItem = objFolder.Self

'Wscript.Echo objFolderItem.Path

Set colItems = objFolder.Items

Dim sCurDir
Dim sFina

For Each objItem in colItems
    'Wscript.Echo objItem.Name
    If InStr(1, objItem.Name, "Google") > 0 Then

      sCurDir =  objFolderItem.Path + "\" + objItem.Name + "\Chrome\User Data\Default\"
      sFina = "History"

      'Wscript.Echo sCurDir + sFina

      Exit For

    End If
Next

    Dim oCS     : oCS       = "Driver={SQLite3 ODBC Driver};Database=@FSPEC@;StepAPI=;Timeout="
    Dim oCNCT   : Set oCNCT = CreateObject( "ADODB.Connection" ) 

    Dim sSQL    : sSQL      = "SELECT * FROM urls"

    Dim oRS
    Dim oFld

    oCS = Replace( oCS, "@FSPEC@", sCurDir + sFina )
    oCNCT.Open oCS
    WScript.Echo "connected to", sCurDir + sFina

    Set oRS = oCNCT.Execute( sSQL )

    For Each oFld In oRS.Fields

    If InStr(1, oFld.Name, "url") > 0 Then

            WScript.Echo oFld.Value

            End If
        Next
        oRS.MoveNext

    oCNCT.Close
    Set oCNCT = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that

```
oCS = Replace( oCS, "@FSPEC@", sCurDir + sFina )
```

results in a decent connection string, the `.Open` should use it. So replace

```
oCNCT.Open sCurDir + sFina
```

with

```
oCNCT.Open oCS
```

Your display loop looks fishy; you probably want to loop over the recordset and access the value of the (one and only) column/field "url".

Comment: I had forgot of install [sqliteodbc](http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/) on my pc. But I'm able to capture only one value from field "url" of "History" Database. So, how I can catch all values (url) stored? I edited my question above, already including with your suggestion.

Comment: I'm waiting your answer about `For Each` loop, for catch all values that contains in field "url" .